# Can someone explain what they mean by Github Pages being static

Tags: github-pages

I understand Github Pages and what they are but don't understand what they mean by them saying they are static. Does it mean you cant get any animations on it?

Answer (score 2):

The term 'static' refers to how the website is delivered. So for GitHub pages, (in general) you create HTML files that are served 'statically', which means as they are. They can still include CSS files with animations, or JavaScript files that manipulate the page.

This is different compared to a system that serves dynamic webpages, which can create and serve pieces of the website page as required from the server end.

For a more thorough explanation, see here:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_web_page)
- [Wix.com](https://www.wix.com/blog/2021/11/static-vs-dynamic-website/)

Comment: To this explanation, I'd like to add that dymanic pages render components of the page in the server, and deliver it back to the page without reloading. Also, while doing this rendering, you can make queries to the database. All of this processing power is done in the servers or backend, and the client (your browser) is not aware of it. A good example of a dynamic website is Facebook, start scrolling down and you'll see how a dynamic website behaves. More: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page